# Stack Snippet "Copy Snippet To Answer" after you have already answered

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I like the new Stack Snippets feature but have a possible suggestion for an improvement. Here is the scenario.

I encounter a question that does not have a stack snippet but just manually marked up code. I answer the question and submit the answer. The user then leaves a comment on my post and I would like to update my answer. In this time the OP has changed their question to now use a Stack Snippet. I wanted to edit their example to show the improvements in my answer so I click on the "Copy Snippet To Answer" button and get an alert asking me if I am sure that I want to create a new answer, obviously I don't, I want to use it in an edit to my current answer. I click edit on my answer and there appears to be no way to copy the snippet into my answer.

Other than clicking edit on the OP's question, copying the stack snippet code, exiting that, then editing my existing answer. Would there be a way to add this functionality to Stack Snippets where we can copy the snippet into an already existing answer as an edit?

Comment: The button copies the snippet to a **new** answer, not an existing one. How would the system know where in your existing post to copy the snippet?

Comment: I completely agree with that statement. So I'm wondering if there could be a way to copy a snippet from the original question into an answer on the edit screen of my answer. It could copy into the current cursor location or default to the bottom or something.

Comment: To clarify I would expect the "Copy Snippet" button to be on the EDIT screen for my answer. Not for it to lookup which answer was mine and then take me to the edit screen and insert it there. So I would click "edit" on my answer, and then there would be an option to "copy snippet from original question" or even better would be a feature like a `git merge` where it would merge in their changes... but that's asking a little much in my opinion, at least while this is still new.

Comment: *"Other than clicking edit on the OP's question, copying the stack snippet code, exiting that, then"*... Why do you have to edit op's question to copy the code..?!!

Comment: @TJ To get all of the markdown. Does all of the markdown copy with the selection from the displayed post?

Comment: @SnareChops Whay do you want *all of the markdown*..? You're gonna copy **code** for the snippet, so what *markdown* you want to copy along with `HTML/CSS/JS`..?

Comment: @TJ the special tags that tell the stack snippets which section is javascript, which is css, and which is html. I believe I misspoke and wrote markdown instead of markup.

Comment: @SnareChops You don't have to copy it at all, You can open a snippet in your answer and paste the code segments in it's respective windows, those comments will be generated automatically by system once you insert the snippet into answer...